# Mac OS Mojave 10.14.1 Trying to Install Old Command Line Tools

Tags: command-line, xcode, mojave

I've just installed Mac OS Mojave 10.14.1 and the latest XCode.

```
➜  ~ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.1
BuildVersion:   18B75
```

I was just running updates and noticed one of them was an old version of the command line tools. It won't stop offering me this, and I'm not sure why. I did recently download the High Sierra installer to make bootable media for another computer, but have since removed it from my hard drive.

Here are the offending command line tools:

```
➜  ~ softwareupdate --list
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
   * Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode-10.1
    Command Line Tools (macOS High Sierra version 10.13) for Xcode (10.1), 190584K [recommended]
```

It looks like I can flag it to be ignored using the `softwareupdate` cli, but I feel like there might be a more systemic issue that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually download it from

[More Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)

until they fix the `Software Update Tool`

There are current reports that they "profile" has been messed up so it lost your information on what OSX and what updates you already have...but that is just my guess.

Comment: Thanks, that's great and all, but I'm pretty sure I already have the tools installed. It just wants to install old tools over it. Or are you suggesting that by installing these manually it will fix the software update issue?

Comment: as far I know they have a bug to fix in they ID system, Mojave is not reporting correctly its version.

Comment: I had this problem, and installing the latest release of command line tools fixed it. I think it stemmed from the fact that when the latest Xcode was released a few days ago, the accompanying command line tools were not yet available (only the beta versions).